# PHP enable concurrent and simultaneous writes to json file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

**Scenario:** I have a website hosted which is being accessed by multiple users (1000+), I have to store their selections/choices in a single json file (on server). I use PHP and JQuery for this.

**Problem:** the code is not able to log data from multiple users. the data is getting overwritten. If I use lock (php) only one user gets to write , and other users data doesnt get saved. I tried append and got horrible results (lots of data repetition)

**Looking for:** A way to allow simultaneous writes to the json file using php without losing or overwriting data. 
Or a better approach for storing these user preferences/choices.

I thought of keeping data in localstorage/sessionstorage and commit write on browser exit, but I couldnt find a foolproof way to always catch a browser exit across various avl versions of IE, Chrome, Firefox, safari.

Comment: why don't use a database??

Comment: There is no solution that will help you without changing from storing all user data in a single file. There are numerous ways to access databases these days either via your host or cloud service. Storage is cheap

Comment: from an architects point of view is it recommended to create a user (login) specific file - one for each user - and store the preferences in the user specific files and then run a job on server to consolidate these files into one at specific interval? the usernames are unique.

As recommended I can consider using a database, but that will need major changes to code and for the time being I am looking for a quick solution.

Comment: I couldn't find a solution and finally moved to using a database instead.Lets close this question.

Comment: Old one, I know. For future solution seekers; an idea that's not all to ineffective in overhead; A "gateway-file" that check if the "main" file is locked; in that case: creates a new file for every request; sorting this when load is less. I remember once when I didn't have access to a classical DB and used SQLite and did something similar

Comment: the author suggested during a comment that it should close